# Smallest order of non-planar posets and lattices

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-orders

I just wonder what is the non-planar posets (reps.lattices) with least amount of elements? Or where can I find such results? Thanks a lot...

By a non-planar poset I mean it admits no Hasse diagram in which no two edges intersect. A sufficient condition for the Hasse diagram to be non-planar is that it is non-planar as a graph, but this is not necessary.

Comment: I still think that "planar poset $\Leftrightarrow$ planar order graph". I agree that for *one* specific drawing of the Hasse diagram, your condition is only sufficient, but this is the same as when we talk about graphs vs embedding (drawing). If you require that the posets admits **no** planar Hasse diagram, then it's equivalent to being non-planar as a graph... Or am I wrong?

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues Well, in fact there is a theorem asserting that for lattices, planarity is equivalent to $\dim\leq 2$, the 8-element lattice you propose (the power set lattice of 3-point set) is 3-dimensional, so must be non-planar as a poset, but it doesn't contain either $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$, so it's planar as a graph... The point is, drawing Hasse diagram has some restriction on height...

Comment: oh okay! Thanks for the info, learnt something new today, I'll have a depper look, seems interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

If by non-planar, you mean with a non-planar Hasse diagram, then using Kuratowski's Theorem, it must contain a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_5$ or of $K_{3,3}$. So it must have at least 5 vertices : given that $K_5$ cannot represent a poset (it contradicts transitivity), then the smallest one is $K_{3,3}$ and achieved by the following poset, ordered by inclusion :

$$ \large\{ \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,5\},\{1,2,3,6\} \large\} $$

This poset is not a lattice though. I would expect the smallest one to be
$$ \large\{ \emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\} \large\} $$

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but I believe $K_{3,3}$ is more complicated than the 6-element poset you propose, which is planar. However, I think the 8-element lattice you propose is non-planar as a poset, though planar as a graph.

Comment: oh yeah sorry, just noticed that this poset does not have $K_{3,3}$ for diagram! sorry! I'll try again ^^